# Is there anyway to open a TWA from a notification tap? (client.focus() fails for TWA but works for chrome tab or installed PWA)

Tags: service-worker, web-push, trusted-web-activity

I have a PWA with web push notifications that is warped in a TWA.
if the TWA is open in the background, then tapping on the notification does nothing.
if i close the TWA, then tapping on the notification opens a new chrome tab or focuses an expecting tab as expected.

here is my service-worker code

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: 'window',
        includeUncontrolled: true,
      })
      .then(function(clientList) {
        for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          const client = clientList[i];
          const isChatAppUrl =
            client.url.includes('.com/messages') ||
            client.url.includes('.co/messages');
          if (isChatAppUrl && 'focus' in client) {
            client.postMessage({
              type: 'NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
              payload: event.notification.data.link,
            });
            return client.focus();
          }
        }
        if (clients.openWindow) {
          return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.link);
        }
      }),
  );
});
```

when debugging the issue with the TWA opened in the background I noticed that `client.focus()` fails with `Not allowed to open a window`

Comment: Can you confirm this works with regular installed PWAs? If that's the case, this may be a bug with Trusted Web Activity.

Comment: yes this does work with regular installed PWAs. focus and openWindow correctly open the pwa. I had hoped that this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1052288&can=2&q=component%3AUI%3EBrowser%3EMobile%3ETrustedWebActivities) was related and would be fixed in chrome 81. but I am getting the same behavior after upgrading to chrome 81

Comment: This does look like a slightly different issue from the one in the bug. The behaviour should be the same with installed PWAs or regular Apps, so sounds like a bug too. Let me know if you want to create a new bug in Chromium. Otherwise, happy to file it.